# Is it possible to use output redirections from a cmd file using start?

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, cmd

I want to have a cmd file with something like:

```
:one
start /wait (blabla1.exe -q -m 1>blabla1.log 2>&1)

:two
start /wait (blabla2.exe -q -m 1>blabla2.log 2>&1)
```

where I want the output of the blabla application not the output of the start command.

Is it even possible to have the redirections "local" inside the start command?

Do I have to create a 1 line cmd containing
`blabla1.exe -q -m 1>blabla1.log 2>&1`
and pass it to the `start` command?

Update: I need the first one (blabla1.exe) to be finished before I launch the 2nd one (blabla2.exe). That's the reason for using `start /wait`.

(Windows XP and up)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that you are redirecting output to a file, and waiting for the process to finish,  is the extra window started by 'start' actually required? In fact, if there WAS some way to redirect the output when using start, then the windows that popped up wouldn't even have any output...making them even more meaningless.

If not, simply remove the "start /wait" and call the exes directly.

If it IS necessary...then I'm not sure.

UPDATE: I am fairly certain just removing the "start /wait" will produce the behavior you desire. See below:

(Create the following batch file: foo.cmd

```
:one
notepad.exe
:two
dir
```

Note that dir will not echo until you close notepad.

Comment: I need the 2nd one to start AFTER the first one has finished. So I guess I need the /wait.

Comment: @Francois - Right - in batch files, when you don't use start, batch files do not continue to the next line until a cmd/exe finishes. It is only when you do use start, that this /wait is necessary to wait until the first exits. Adding sample batch script to demonstrate

Comment: You're right I don't need `start` in the first place, then I don't need `/wait`. Just without, it works as I intended. Thanks! {why do it simple when you can do it complicated! sigh ;-) }

Answer (score 22):

Yes it is possible to redirect output using start wait command using the /B switch.

```
start /B /wait myprog.exe >> output.log
```

If you need to break in you will have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will be ignored.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape > characters to be evaluated inside start command

```
start /B /wait myprog.exe ^>^> output.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Translating the OP's original sample code, my solution would be:

```
:one
start /wait cmd.exe "/c blabla1.exe -q -m 1>blabla1.log 2>&1"

:two
start /wait cmd.exe "/c blabla2.exe -q -m 1>blabla2.log 2>&1"
```

The quotes cause the redirects to be done by the programs that are started, instead of by the start command itself.

Background:
I stumbled upon this question because I have a similar problem, and although the OP didn't need to use "start /wait" and could have just omitted that part and not have any trouble with the redirects, my problem is that I do need to use "start", and needed a way to be able to redirect the output of the process to a file.

So, using "start /B" is one solution, but I found that using "start /B" inside my cmd script (which is a domain user's login script in my case) prevents it from terminating when it reaches the end. The console window just hangs there, instead of disappearing. Therefore I had to come up with a new solution.